# How to store values from a particular key from an object into an array - Vue

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object, vuejs2

I have to say, I am new to the whole Vue framework.  I have created a selectable table. The data selected from this table is stored in an object.  This function should run in the back. So, I think I should run it the computed section.  My object looks like this. I am trying to retrieve only the ids. This data is stored in the variable selected.

```
[ { "id": 5, "name": "CD", "box": "A5", "spot": 1 }, { "id": 2, ""name": "DVD", "box": "A2", "spot": 1 } ]
```

I would like to only retrieve the values from the key id. These values should be stored in an array. The array should be pushed when the submit button is clicked. I will later use this array to store this information in this array into a database.

You can find my code below. I guess I am missing something because it doesn't seem to work.  How should I refer to this function that it runs automatically and that the array can be called in my controller to put it into the database?
Thanks for the help.

## Template

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-2">
      <b-form-input v-model="date" class="form-control" type="date" value="getDate" ></b-form-input>
      <pre class="mt-3 mb-0">{{ date }}</pre>
   </div>
   <div class="col-6">
      <b-form-input v-model="description" placeholder="Enter some text"></b-form-input>
      <pre class="mt-3 mb-0">{{ description }}</pre>
   </div>
   <!-- Submit data to db -->
   <div class="col-4">
      <button class="btn btn-primary custom-button-width" center-block>Request antibody pool</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

## JavaScript

```js
data() {
  return {
    // data from db
    data: this.testerdata,
    // selected is the object where my selected data is stored.
    selected: [],
    // here should my id end up
    selectedids: {},
    description: '',
    date: '',
  }
},
computed: {
  tester() {
    var array = [];
    for (var test in this.selected) {
      if (test == "id") {
        array += this.selected[test];
      }
    }
    console.log(array);
  }
},
methods: {
  storeData: async function() {
    axios.post('/panel', {
      description: this.description,
      date: this.date,
      selectedids: this.tester(selectedids)
    }).then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }).finally(function() {
      // always executed
    });
  },
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
array += this.selected[test];
```

This the way to add an item to an array:

```
array.push(this.selected[test]);
```

Additionally, you are trying to loop over properties of `this.selected`, but it is an array which contains objects and has no properties.  Instead, you want to loop over each object item in the array and `push` the `id` property.

And, since `this.selected` is an array, not an object, you should not use a `for...in` loop-- which is for objects-- because the order will not be guaranteed.  You can read more about that in the [MDN `for...in` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in).

You could use a normal `for` loop or the array's [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop.  I'll show the `forEach`:

```
this.selected.forEach(obj => {
    array.push(obj.id);
});
```

Comment: Selected is where my data is stored when something a row in my table is selected. So, selected is the object that holds my data. Is there something wrong with my loop? Should I also show the code of how I push my data into the object? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ok, so `selected`, an array, holds multiple objects.  I will edit my answer to show how your loop should look and explain why not to use `for...in`.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you might be looking for vanilla Javascript answer here. 
However a lot of code can be saved if you can use [RamdaJS](https://ramdajs.com/) library to solve such issues.

It has an excellent set of functions like [pluck](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pluck), which will do the same thing in 1 line.

```
let array = R.pluck('id')(this.selected);
```